Simplify a match nested in a hypothesis in Coq
I'm trying to prove a hypothesis in Coq:
Context {A : Type}.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint subst_kth_element (l : list A) (k: nat) (e: A): list A :=
  match k, l with
    | O, x :: l' => e :: l'
    | O, [] => []
    | S j, [] => []
    | S j, x :: t => x :: subst_kth_element t j e
  end.

Lemma virer2 (l l': list A) (k: nat) (e: A):
  l' = subst_kth_element l k e -> length l = length l'.
Proof.
  intro.
  induction l.
  unfold subst_kth_element in H.

Here I get
Goal 1

l' : list A
k : nat
e : A
H : l' = match k with
         | 0 | _ => []
         end
(1 / 2)
length [] = length l'

In order to conclude, I'd like to simplify the match k with | 0 | _ => [] end to [], but simpl H fails in Cannot coerce H to an evaluable reference. May be because of the l'=, I don't know.
How can I conclude?

Try destruct k.

destruct k in H works. Thanks.

Here is how I'd go about it.  Notice that, to begin with, I have "simplified" the definition, which leads to proofs that are simpler and more easily reflect the structure of the definition.
From Coq Require Import List.

Import ListNotations.

Context {A : Type}.

Fixpoint subst_kth_element (l : list A)
    (k : nat) (e : A) : list A :=
  match l, k with
    | [], _ => []
    | x :: t, O   => e :: t
    | x :: t, S j => x ::
        subst_kth_element t j e
  end.

Lemma virer2 : forall l l' k e,
  l' = subst_kth_element l k e ->
  length l' = length l.
Proof.
  induction l as [|x t]
  ; intros l' k e E'.
  - rewrite E'.
    reflexivity.
  - rewrite E'.
    destruct k as [|k'].
    + reflexivity.
    + cbn.
      apply f_equal.
      apply (IHt _ k' e).
      reflexivity.
Qed.


As great as other times. Thanks.
